# How to wait with select(2) for socket closed for writing

Tags: sockets, select, eof, fclose

Is there a way to wait with `select(2)` for a socket where the peer has called `shutdown(SHUT_RD)` on its socket or has completely closed its socket?

Trying to write to such a socket will return `EPIPE` (Broken Pipe).  I'd like to be notified of this condition before I try to write.

In a server I use `select(2)` to wait for new subscribers connecting via TCP, and for input on other fds to be forwarded to subscribers.  If a subscriber closes its connection, or only shuts down its READ side, I'd like to close my side of the socket immediately and free associated resources.

I tried waiting for exceptions with `select(2)` but that didn't report closed sockets.  Waiting for read on the sockets to the subscribers also won't work, since waiting for read will only return if the socket is closed completely and `read(2)` would return with EOF.

Comment: Just switch to using `poll` and look for `POLLHUP` (and/or `POLLRDHUP` if available)

Comment: @Useless: this will be triggered if the peer has closed the socket or SHUT_WR, but not not with SHUT_RD as asked by the OP.

Comment: You're quite right. I've never seen anyone actually use `shutdown(SHUT_RD)` and it didn't occur to me

Answer (score 1):

Shutting down the socket for reading (`SHUT_RD`) is a purely local action and it is not propagated to the peer in any way. So it is not possible to wait for this. Only shutting down the socket for writing (`SHUT_WR`) is propagated by sending a FIN. And this is the same for completely closing the socket, which is thus indistinguishable by the peer from `SHUT_WR`.

Waiting for the peer to close the socket or to `SHUT_WR` is the same as waiting for the socket to be readable. Only that `recv` will not return any data in this case but return 0, i.e. no data but no error.

But even if there would be a notification by the peer when `SHUT_RD` is done (again, there is no such notification) it would not actually be safe rely on it before writing. Because it would take some time for this notification to arrive from the peer, i.e. there would be an unavoidable race condition.

Therefore, you need to structure your code so that it can properly handle `EPIPE`.

Comment: I have code to handle EPIPE already.  I only thought I could release resources in the server earlier, before trying to write, i.e. when the client closes its socket or even does only SHUT_RD.  I will add acting on seeing EOF when the remote socket is closed and that should be fine also.  Thanks for your answer.